# PCB footprint recommendations for FPC soldering

Tags: pcb-design, footprint, fpc

I'm considering making a PCB to which I would directly solder an OLED display like [this](http://www.buydisplay.com/default/serial-spi-1-3-inch-128x64-oled-display-module-ssd1306-white-on-black); it has a 30-pin, 0.7 mm-pitch FPC connector (a link to the datasheet is on the page).

What's the right way to design a footprint for this kind of connection? Are there any resources that provide a recommended footprint or at least some general guidelines for the geometry and positioning? (For example, how long should the pads be? Should they be bigger than the FPC contacts, and in which directions?)

Comment: If you have the space, for a first try for hand assembly I'd make pads the same width and about 1.5x as long.  If you don't have the space, pre-tinning and careful reheating through the ribbon with a big curved tip might do it with entirely covered pads. (Unfortunately the one I did is hidden under the display, so cant readily check it for you). For automated, ask the folks who have to make that work.

Comment: @ChrisStratton that's worthy of being an answer.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it necessarily right, just what I got away with on a handmade prototype.  Was just able to find my design files - I used pads that were 0.5x2mm for a device that seemed to have a slightly coarser 0.8mm pitch (and only 14 pins).

Answer (score 1):

Well you start with the datasheet that gives you the dimensions of the connector itself.  From there you could look up the ipc specs that actually has the info you are asking for but I think you have pay for those.

Also check this [tool](http://www.pcblibraries.com) out it has a free version with wizards that help make footprints.